# unsigned int mysql in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

In mysql I declared fields of type unsigned int. They defaulted to INT(10) UNSIGNED. In my c# code when I try to read in these values to an uint type it gives me an error saying
"cannot convert long into an uint". 
Is there anything I am missing here. I thought BIGINT was supposed to be long and int(10) unsigned was supposed to be uint? 
I am using entity framework to read in the values...
Thanks

CODE

```
from employee in model.employees 
select new EmployeeEntity { 
  EmpID = employee.EmpID, 
  FirstName=employee.FirstName
};
```

`EmpID` is declared as `UNSIGNED INT 10` in mysql

`EmployeeEntity` declares `EmpID` as `uint` (I tried uint32 as well). However the line

The assignment "EmpID = employee.EmpID" gives me the error...

Comment: Which EF provider are you using?

Comment: edited the post to include code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is provider trouble. It converts types between DBMS and application with errors. I recommend you to ask their support or change provider.

As for me - I'm using Devart dotConnect for MySQL. Its mapping table is provided here - http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/DataTypeMapping.html

Comment: Are you sure it is provider trouble? - The following is the feature request for Entity Framework, which still not supports this, so doesn't this indicate that the trouble is not a matter of the persistence provider (and thus not resolvable by switching to another one if ever available), but one level above, in EF in general? https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2085127-support-unsigned-integer-e-g-uint-properties-an

Comment: Furthermore, I have a similar issue with SQL Anywhere, but concerning writing (reading was a prob too, but only for primary keys and we could solve that): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142250/ef-4-0-30319-sql-anywhere-11-0-1-writing-uint-column-fails. Did you have any more insight in the meantime and may know how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The sounds like an issue with the EF Provider. It might be that the value is simply retrieved as a long. But since you know its a uint you can simply cast it from long to uint.
But try to check if there is a newer version of the EF Provider that maps the types correctly.

Comment: And the latest mysql connector. Think its 6.3.5

Comment: Hi @ntziolis, I have a similar issue with SQL Anywhere, but concerning writing:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142250/ef-4-0-30319-sql-anywhere-11-0-1-writing-uint-column-fails
Did you have any more insight in the meantime and may know how I could solve this?